# Access to resource data in rest client DELETE method (or custom params)?

Tags: admin-on-rest

I need to access an items field when handling the DELETE case in my rest client. This is because the rest server needs a custom header to be set (etag to handle concurrency).  In the UPDATE case I just did the following as I made the etag a readonly field:

`options.headers.set('If-Match', params.data._etag)`

Can anyone point me in the right direction here, I'm guessing I need to implement a custom param or something but not sure where to begin?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `CRUD_DELETE` action simply passes the object ID - not the `previousData` as the `CRUD_UPDATE` action. To get what you need, you must patch admin-on-rest.

Once you do that, I suggest you make a Pull Request, this may interest other developers!